# boost::bind with dynamic argument?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I have a container of Person objects. Using **std::for_each** and **boost::bind**, I am trying to append each one to an XML object (specifically, of type **pugi::xml_node**).

I have a Decorator class. It contains functions that take in an object (eg, a Person type) and a pugi::xml_node, and then use the data in the object to populate the pugi::xml_node object.

Eg:

```
class Decorator
{
    public:
        decoratePersonNode(const Person &person, pugi::xml_node node);
        // ... many other functions
}
```

For every object in my container of Person objects, I would like to append a new node to a parent node, and then 'decorate' that new node using the Person object.

So I have something like this:

```
pugi::xml_node parentNode("People");
for_each(people.begin(), people.end(), boost::bind(&Decorator::decoratePersonNode, m_decorator, _1, parentNode.append_child()));
```

This is wrong, however. parentNode.append_child() gets called once, and that object is then passed as an argument for every call to decoratePersonNode(). What I want is for every iteration to **call** parentNode.append_child() and pass that to decoratePersonNode().

I know that I could modify the decoratePersonNode() function to accept the *parent* node as a parameter, and then call append_child() within, but I do not want to do that.

I don't want to modify the arguments of decoratePersonNode() in any way :)

**EDIT: I should also have mentioned! I'm not using C++11.**

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: With an algorithm as simple as for_each, an explicite loop will be a lot easier than bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap up `decoratPersonNode` with another `functor` or `lambda`. It would look like:

```
for_each(people.begin(), people.end(), 
         [&parentNode, &m_decorator](const Person& person) {
             m_decorator.decoratePersonNode(person, parentNode.append_child());
         });
```

Comment: I should have mentioned! I'm not using C++11, so can't use the C++11 lambda functions (unless the same thing is possible with boost?). Thank you so much, though!

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can implement a `functor` yourself, and pass it to `for_each`. `lambda` is almost syntax sugar of `functor`.

Comment: Thanks for that Xiaotian! I have a lot of similar 'decorator' functions, but I implemented a functor taking a function pointer as a parameter, and it worked beautifully. Much appreciated!